# How to multipy numbers between a field and a new created field

Tags: javascript

Please i have a problem here in my work i have an `input` field and have a `button` that i use to create new `input` field with `onclick` event, but my problem is how to multiply numbers in both `input` fields and alert the answer.

```
 function create(){
      var main_input = document.getElementById("main_input").value,
      newinput = document.createElement('input');
      newinput.placeholder = "test1";
      newinput.value;
      document.getElementById("mytest").appendChild(newinput);
 }

 function multiply(){
     var ans = newinput * main_input;
     alert(ans);
 }
```

Comment: These variables are scoped inside the `create` function and they are not available inside the `multiply` function. Anyways - do you want to multiply a DOM element and a number?

Comment: While trying to format your code I encountered an odd comma - is that a typo during copy/paste or is it really in your code `("main_input").value,`?

Comment: "_how to multiply numbers in both input field and alert the answser_" Do you know how to get text from a field? Do you know how to do a multiplication of 2 numbers? Do you know how to do an alert? Which _exact_ step can you not complete?

Comment: @csm_dev it's not a type, it's multi-line declaration.

Comment: Please post your html!

Comment: Francis please think of [accepting an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of clarity, I am posting this solution. Looks like you are not clear on few concepts so let me try to explain them:

1. You need to move your variables outside the scope of create() so that they are available in the multiply() function.
2. You cannot just multiply two input fields. You need to take the values from them as shown in the code below.

Hopefully it helps you in moving ahead!

```js
var main_input,newinput;
function create(){
  main_input = document.getElementById("main_input");
  newinput = document.createElement('INPUT');
  newinput.placeholder = "test1";
  newinput.value = 10;
  document.getElementById("mytest").appendChild(newinput);
}
function multiply(){
var ans = newinput.value * main_input.value;
alert(ans);
}

create();
multiply();
```

```html
<input id="main_input" value=10 />
<div id="mytest"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [eval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) or you can manually multiply the values like `input1.value * input2.value`

```js
function create(){
            // this is unnecessary, you are creating a new element
            // var main_input = document.getElementById("main-input");
            var newinput = document.createElement('input');
            newinput.placeholder = "test1";
            newinput.id = 'test1'; // give the element an id, to access it later by id
            // newinput.value; // this too is unnecessary, you'll get the value from the user
            if (!document.getElementById('test1')) {
                // append the child only if it doesn't exist
                document.getElementById("mytest").appendChild(newinput);
            }
        }
        function multiply(){
            var newinput = document.getElementById('test1');
            var mainInput = document.getElementById("main_input");
            alert(eval(newinput.value + '*' + mainInput.value));
            // alert(newinput.value * mainInput.value) you can also use this method
        }
```

```html
<div id="mytest">
    <input type="text" id="main_input">
</div>
<button onclick="create()">Create</button>
<button onclick="multiply()">Multiply</button>
```